# Field is required on POST requets with GeoFeatureModelSerializer and ListCreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postgis, geodjango, django-rest-framework-gis

it was hard to find a good title for this thread.
I'm developping webservices with django, geodjango (postgis), django-rest-framework and rest_framework_gis. Those webservices will be used in interactive maps.

One of my model is the following:

```
class Polygon(models.Model):
    fk_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)  # the owner of this polygon (User)
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)  # id in data warehouse
    func_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)  # e.g 'field', 'building', ...  
    coordinates = models.PolygonField()
    properties = JSONField(default={})  # JSON containing attributes and actions
```

The serializer of this model:

```
class PolygonSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Polygon
        geo_field = "coordinates"
        fields = ('external_id', 'fk_owner', 'func_type', 'properties')
```

And the endpoint

```
class FieldList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PolygonSerializer
    lookup_field = 'external_id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'external_id_field'

    def get_queryset(self):
        id_user = User.objects.get(external_id=self.kwargs['external_id_user']).id
        queryset = Polygon.objects.filter(func_type="field").filter(fk_owner=id_user).all()
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = User.objects.get(external_id=self.kwargs['external_id_user'])
        serializer.save(fk_owner=user)
```

When I use the following curl request:

```
curl -X POST http://xxx.yyy.zzz/api/v2/users/aZ523AsZm/fields/ -d '{"external_id": "aE15feg64AzaP", "func_type": "field", "coordinates": "POLYGON((62780.8532226825 5415035.177460473, 62941.3759284064 5415283.89540161, 63187.058044587146 5415364.391565912, 63257.96856022246 5414992.852982632, 62780.8532226825 5415035.177460473, 62780.8532226825 5415035.177460473))", "properties": {"a": "b"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I get `{"fk_owner":["This field is required."],"external_id":["This field is required."],"coordinates":["This field is required."],"func_type":["This field is required."]}`

**However, when I replace GeoFeatureModelSerializer by a simple ModelSerializer, eveything is fine. Why ?**

It took me like 1 hour to find the guilty, and it's soon the end of the daywork for me. Any help would be appreciate ! Thanks, and sorry for the long post.

**[EDIT 10/11]**: My workaround is to use 2 serializers: one for GET and one for CREATE
    class PolygonList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = Point.objects.all()
        filter_backends = (drfg_filters.InBBoxFilter,)

```
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            self.serializer_class = PolygonSerializerCreate
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            self.serializer_class = PolygonSerializerRetrieve
        return self.serializer_class
```

Comment: Have you tried sending GeoJSON in the POST instead of normal JSON?

Comment: Yes, and its still the same error message

Comment: Could you write a failing unit test and send a pull request to the repo?
If it's a bug I can fix it, if the code is not correct I can help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [django-rest-framework-gis](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis) repo contains a few examples of a POST request to create new objects, for example take a look at this one:

- [unit test code](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis/blob/master/tests/django_restframework_gis_tests/tests.py#L36-L68)
- [view code](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis/blob/master/tests/django_restframework_gis_tests/views.py#L10-L16)
- [serializer code](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis/blob/master/tests/django_restframework_gis_tests/serializers.py#L24-L29)
- [model code](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis/blob/master/tests/django_restframework_gis_tests/models.py#L12-L42)

As you can see, POSTing should work, if it doesn't, it's either a bug or the code you are using is wrong.

From the what you posted in your question it looks like the JSON format you are using is not right. You told me you tried to send GeoJSON in the POST request, but I ask you to take a careful look at the links I just posted and try again. If you think it's a bug, we should test it and fix it.

Federico

Comment: Hello, I will go on another project next week but I will inform the next developer to have a look. I'm pretty sure I made a mistake but right now I've got no time to investigate. Thank you for your tips